# Custard Pudding tasting like raw eggs

Tags: eggs, sugar, custard, pudding

So this is my first time trying to make a custard pudding(I've watched a video). And of course it came out looking horrible but I left it on the stove for 30mins. I used 2 eggs and 250ml of milk and sugar. After I took out I tried it out but it tastes a little like raw eggs. But it's slightly consistent, I am just afraid of eating it since I've read some articles about diseases that one can get from consuming raw eggs. So my question is: Is it safe to eat it knowing that it was on the stove for more than 30mins ? Although it tastes a little like raw eggs, it was hot enough to burn my tongue when I took it out of the stove.

Note: The water on the pan even boiled.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you heated the eggs above 160°F/70°C (and boiling is definitely above that), they're cooked, and any harmful bacteria has been killed. Can't say for sure that you did this without knowing the steps you performed.

Given, if it doesn't taste good, and it was cheap ingredients... sounds like an argument to discard it anyway. Even if its perfectly safe.

(Note: lower temperatures will also kill the bacteria, but it's no longer instant—you may have to hold it for a few minutes to a few hours, depending on the temperature.)